# Confused about javascript generator function

Tags: javascript

Why the value of the final `b` is not 24 but 18?
I think when function `s2` is called the last time, `a` is `12` and `last` is `2`, so `b` should be equal to `12 * 2 = 24`.

```js
let a = 1, b = 2;

function* foo() {
  a++;
  yield;
  b = b * a;
  a = (yield b) + 3;
}

function* bar() {
  b--;
  yield;
  a = (yield 8) + b;
  b = a * (yield 2);
}

function step(gen) {
  let it = gen();
  let last;

  return function () {
    last = it.next(last).value;
  };
}

let s1 = step(foo);
let s2 = step(bar);

s2(); //b=1 last=undefined

s2(); //last=8

s1(); //a=2 last=undefined

s2(); //a=9 last=2

s1(); //b=9 last=9

s1(); //a=12

s2(); //b=24

console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: source of the question is [You don't know Javascript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/sync-async/ch4.md) Sync/Async Chapter 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line of the `bar` function:

```
b = a * (yield 2);
```

the code already ran the `a *` before running `(yield 2)`. So it would seem that `a` is already evaluated at that point.

If you move the multiplication by `a` to after `(yield 2)`, then it seems `a` is evaluated after `(yield 2)` is run, thereby ensuring you get the most up to date value of `a`.

So the last line of the `bar` function could become:

```
b = (yield 2) * a;
```

This can be seen in the example below.

```js
let a = 1, b = 2;

function* foo() {
  a++;
  yield;
  b = b * a;
  a = (yield b) + 3;
}

function* bar() {
  b--;
  yield;
  a = (yield 8) + b;
  b = (yield 2) * a;
}

function step(gen) {
  let it = gen();
  let last;

  return function () {
    last = it.next(last).value;
  };
}

let s1 = step(foo);
let s2 = step(bar);

s2(); //b=1 last=undefined

s2(); //last=8

s1(); //a=2 last=undefined

s2(); //a=9 last=2

s1(); //b=9 last=9

s1(); //a=12

s2(); //b=24

console.log(a, b);
```